# Conditional statements with SCSS

Tags: class, conditional-statements, sass

Does anyone know if this is possible:

I want my brand colour to be `$brand: #00cccc;`

however, I want to change that on just one page, and that page is defined by a class on it's body.

```
body class="purple"
```

Now my mind is thinking that this would be ideal:

```
body.$class { 
    @if $class == 'purple'
    { 
        $brand = #ff0033;
    }
    @else 
    {
        $brand = #00cccc;
    }
}
```

But that's not correct syntax at all.

Is this something that can be done in a similar way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this?

```
@each $class in purple, none {
  $brand: #00cccc;
  $selector: 'body';
  @if $class == purple {
    $brand: #ff0033;
    $selector: 'body.' + $class;
  }
  #{$selector}{
    /* Use $brand */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as of 2022 Sass does include `@if` and `@else` rules for flow control. [More info on the Sass documentation site.](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/if)

> The @if rule is written @if  { ... }, and it controls whether or not its block gets evaluated (including emitting any styles as CSS). The expression usually returns either true or false—if the expression returns true, the block is evaluated, and if the expression returns false it’s not.

For example, this Sass code:

```
$light-background: #f2ece4;
$light-text: #036;
$dark-background: #6b717f;
$dark-text: #d2e1dd;

@mixin theme-colors($light-theme: true) {
  @if $light-theme {
    background-color: $light-background;
    color: $light-text;
  } @else {
    background-color: $dark-background;
    color: $dark-text;
  }
}

.banner {
  @include theme-colors($light-theme: true);
  body.dark & {
    @include theme-colors($light-theme: false);
  }
}
```

...will produce this CSS:

```
.banner {
  background-color: #f2ece4;
  color: #036;
}
body.dark .banner {
  background-color: #6b717f;
  color: #d2e1dd;
}
```

There is also support for `@else if` and Boolean operators [`and`, `or`, and `not`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/operators/boolean).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is an @if statement you could create for that. In LESS you could redeclare the same variable inside `body.purple` and it would only apply inside that block, but in Sass/Scss redeclaring the variable will change it globally. This might not be ideal but you could redeclare the variable twice, once at the top for the purple color, and once at the bottom to set it back to its default value.

**scss**

```
// Global Variables
$blue: #0cc;
$purple: #f03;
$brand: $blue;

body {
    color: $brand; // blue
}

.purple {
    $brand: $purple;

    color: $brand; // now purple
    // all other styles

    $brand: $blue;
}

.test {
    color: $brand; // back to blue
}
```

**css output**

```
body {
  color: #00cccc;
}

.purple {
  color: #ff0033;
}

.test {
  color: #00cccc;
}
```

Here is an article about the variable scope differences between LESS and Sass. http://blog.freeside.co/post/41774744757/less-vs-sass-variable-scopes

Comment: This would mean redeclaring all the styles again, effectively, reducing my love for scss