# Know if the class exists with scss

Tags: css, sass

**Short description:**

I'm using scss with compass, I need to know that the class exists or not.

**Long Description:**

What I'm trying to do is create a mixin for margin. We can pass the margin we need for all the dimensions and if will check dose any class exists for that dimensions if yes than it will extent it else will apply the dimension. For example:

I already have .mr5 class which is

```
 .mr5 { margin-right: 5px; }
```

Now if the value passed in the mixin for the right dimension is 5 than I want to check if first something like

```
if ( exist .mr5 ) { @extend .mr5; } else { right: $dimension; }
```

Comment: or I have created a array for example $mp-distance: 0,5,10,15,20; can I know that the the parameter passed exists in the $mp-distance or not. ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to check for the existence of a class. I found [this issue on the Sass github page](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/826), which asks for something similar, but got closed with the following comment that you can use the `!optional` flag for this:

*[The !optional flag is provided for handling classes and placeholders that may not exist.](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/826)*

For example:

```
.<your_class> {
  .mr5 { margin-right: 5px; }
  }
  <your_selector> {
    @extend .mr5 !optional;
  }
}
```

See also the [SASS reference on this flag](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#the__flag) for more info.

Comment: oks means " @extend .mr5 !optional; " will only execute if there is .mr5 class ?

Comment: Yes, I think that's how you could interpret it. However, looking at purely code execution level, I think it always executes, but it won't throw any errors when the .mr-5 doesn't exist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71444156/2753555 It has better answer