# If class exists do X

Tags: loops, class, sass

I have a list of icons.
The idea is to map them to a different icon set.
If the class of the icons doesn't exist, I want to give it a color, so it is easy to spot which ones are not set.

```html
$icons:
peter        spider,
bruce        hulk,
tony         iron;
```

is there a way to detect something like `@if .class == null { }` in Sass??

```html
.gg-spider{
    color: red;
}

.gg-hulk{
    color: green;
}

/////////////////// 

@mixin iconmixin($glyph, $gg, $after){
    .glyph-#{$glyph}{
        @extend .gg-#{$gg} !optional;
        @if .gg-#{$gg} != 'null'{
            color: purple;
        }
    }
}


$icons:
peter           spider,
bruce           hulk,
tony            iron;


@each $icon in $icons {
    @include iconmixin(#{nth($icon, 1)}, #{nth($icon, 2)}, #{nth($icon, 3)});
}
```

this is my broken code thus far.
I hope someone can help me out.
(I tried `content-exists()`, but I can't seem to figure out how this works)

Comment: Why not having a default color instead and using the cascading ? Have you tried moving `color: purple;` before your `@extend` ? (without the `if` statement)

Comment: just adding this link, also talks about detecting if a class exists.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983131/know-if-the-class-exists-with-scss

Comment: I still think that you are overthinking it and that you should do it differently.